# Custom border for a fieldset and legend

Tags: html, css, legend, fieldset

sorry if this question has been asked before, my friend asked me to do this sort of fieldset for their website.

screenshot in this link

[image: custom fieldset border]

it looks like a normal one but I'm curious how do I get that little vertical line on the left and the right side of "Aim to preserve" text.

Help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements in order to style these two specific vertical lines:

```css
fieldset {
  border:1px solid gray;
}
legend {
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 90%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
legend:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  left: 0px;
  top: 7px;
}
legend:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 8px;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  right: 0px;
  top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Subscription info</legend>
    <label for="name">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <br />
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" />
    <br />
    <label for="address">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="40" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: This ought to be accepted as the answer, since it straightforwardly answers the question, and even includes a working snippet.

Comment: @ElliottJones thanks for your comment. I'm not sure that the original poster is still available here to accept this answer. But thanks for your vote :)

Comment: no problem. It bugs me when I see someone on SO go through the trouble of thoroughly answering a question with few responses but doesn't get the green check mark, especially when the only other answer given purports to be an improvement but is broken. Cheers and thank you.

Comment: This one works in chrome 90, but not firefox 88.

Comment: @Stephen - made some changes in the example, it should work with firefox 88 now as well. Please check and let me know if there are any more issues.

Comment: If you are using bootstrap just add to legend `width: unset!important;` and it will work like magic

Answer (score -4):

**Here** is some improvement.

```css
fieldset {
  border:1px solid gray;
}
legend {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%; 
     /* Move the legend to the center of the fieldset's top border */

  transform: translateX(-50%); 
     /* Fix the alignment to center perfectly */

  background-color: white; 
     /* Put whatever color you want */

  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  color: gray;
  font-size:90%;
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
}
legend:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  left: 0px;
  top: 7px;
}
legend:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 8px;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  right: 0px;
  top: 7px;
}
#line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px; /* Position the line */
  left: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  min-width: 20%; /* Fix this according to the white space to hide */
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
 <!-- Add a div here to make up a line to hide
         the space left by the legend -->
  <div id="line"></div>
  <legend>Subscription info</legend>
    <label for="name">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <br />
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" />
    <br />
    <label for="address">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="40" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Have you ran the snippet? Theres a massive hole in the middle and the label is at the side?

Comment: This one works in firefox 88, but not chrome 90.